# Extract sub_array value from wordpress array in the database and save it back

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have data stored in a custom field in array as such

```
a:5:{i:0;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:44:"Value1";}i:1;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:24:"Value2";}i:2;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:31:"Value3";}i:3;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:41:"Value4";}i:4;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:39:"Value5";}}
```

I want to extract the values of the sub_array product_desc and update the custom field meta_value.

I know wordpress have maybe_unserialize to unserialize the data but what to do next to extract the sub_array values?

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( 'migrate' !== filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'action' ) ) {
        return;
    }
 
    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'any',
    ] );
    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return;
    }
 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        
        $field_id_1 = 'podu';
        $field_value_1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, true );
        $data = maybe_unserialize( $field_value_1 );

      //How to extract sub_array values from $data?
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$data` contains an array, so you can loop over it:

```
foreach($data as $singleData){
    $desc[] = $singleData['product_desc'];
    ... now you have your $desc
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. There is a typo in singleData. I used your code. It worked but one only item was saved in the db from the array.

Comment: thanks, i correct my typo in answer, if it.

if you want to save multiple value, you have to change the field name

Comment: Thanks for the update. Wordpress can save multiple values as an array afaik. I don't want to save individual value in multiple fields. Just one field and row in a serialized array. I want to save it like ``a:3:{i:0;s:3:"Value1";i:1;s:3:"Value2";i:2;s:3:"Value3";}`` from current ``a:5:{i:0;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:44:"Value1";}i:1;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:24:"Value2";}i:2;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:31:"Value3";}i:3;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:41:"Value4";}i:4;a:1:{s:12:"product_desc";s:39:"Value5";}}``

Comment: I got it. I just needed to add [] after $desc in your first solution. This works fine. ``foreach($data as $singleData){
    $desc[] = $singleData['product_desc'];
}``

Comment: Please update your solution with your first code and []. I will mark it as solved and close it.